# Dynamically create Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

Given a strings like 'param1.param2.param3' and a value that should be set on the last parameter, is there a better way than the following to dynamically create an Object and reuse the function to create more parameters on the Object, some which may share a parent parameter? This function also assumes every parameter on the parent Object is an Object with parameters. The purpose is to construct a JSON Object dynamically for a PUT/PATCH request.

```
function(o,prop,val) {
            prop = prop.split('.');
            prop.forEach(function(property,i){
                if(i===0 && typeof(o[property]) === 'undefined'){
                    o[property] = {};
                    if(prop.length === 2){
                        o[prop[0]][prop[1]] = val;
                    }
                }
                else if(i===1 && typeof(o[prop[0]][property]) === 'undefined'){
                    o[prop[0]][property] = {};
                    if(prop.length === 3){
                        o[prop[0]][prop[1]][prop[2]] = val;
                    }
                } else if(i===1 && typeof(o[prop[0]][property]) === 'object'){
                    if(prop.length === 3){
                        o[prop[0]][prop[1]][prop[2]] = val;
                    }
                }
                else if(i===2 && typeof(o[prop[0]][prop[1]][property]) === 'undefined'){
                    o[prop[0]][prop[1]][property] = {};
                    if(prop.length === 4){
                        o[prop[0]][prop[1]][prop[2]][prop[3]] = val;
                    }
                } else if(i===2 && typeof(o[prop[0]][prop[1]][property]) === 'object'){
                    if(prop.length === 4){
                        o[prop[0]][prop[1]][prop[2]][prop[3]] = val;
                    }
                }
            });
            return o;
        };
```

Here is a Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cn25o1vf/

Comment: You might also want to add a demo to prove that this code isn't broken, or at least we can see how it works.

Comment: @Jamal confirmed the title

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer added a Fiddle

Comment: You may wish to indicate the desired result. For instance, in that fiddle, it adds a property named "another" with an empty object as a value (in JSON: `'{ "another": {} }'`), whereas I would have expected it to create a property with the string `"object"`, iow: `'{ "another": "object" }'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems odd to special-case the string `"object"` when preparing an object for serialization, so I came up with the following code:

```
var createObjectFromParam = function (o, prop, val) {
    var parts = prop.split('.');
    var last = o;
    while (parts.length) {
        var part = parts.shift();
        if (parts.length > 0) {
            last[part] = last[part] || {};
            last = last[part];
        } else {
            last[part] = val; // Add conditional expressions here
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

The code does the following:

- Creates a temporary variable (`last`) to contain the current "level" of the object hierarchy.
- Loops through the array. Note that `while (parts.length)` will stop the loop when there are no longer parts in the array.
- Take the next part of the `prop`. [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) pulls the first element of the array out.
- If we're not at the last element

  - If the element with the specified name exists at the level, use that
  - If not, create an object at that level
- Otherwise, add a property with the specified value to the object.
- Finally, return the created object.

Given the example in the jsFiddle [(updated here)](https://jsfiddle.net/cn25o1vf/2/), this would produce the following structure:

```
{
    "ready": {
        "set": "go"
    },
    "another": "object",
    "happy": {
        "happy": {
            "joy": "joy",
            "foo": "bar",
            "happy": "happy"
        }
    }
}
```

To keep that original special-casing, just replace the commented line with something like:

```
last[part] = val === 'object' ? {} : val === 'undefined' ? : undefined : val;
```